# How to pass a register array to a buffer with single bit input and outputs in Verilog?

Tags: verilog

I have a tristate buffer called BUF. I don't know how this buffer is implemented but I know that it has two inputs (I and T) and one output (O) and one bidirectional port (IO). I know that all these ports are single bits.

Now, I have a register array (data) and a direction register (dir). Is this code valid:

```
reg [15:0] data;
reg dir;
wire [15:0] output;

//more code here

BUF my_buf
(
.I(data),
.T(dir),
.O(output),
.IO(to_phys_pin) //to_phys_pin is a 16bit long array going to the physical pins
)
```

Specifically, will this code create 16 instances of buffers for me, all of them sharing the same "dir" register as the T parameter? Or do I have to use "generate" to generate 15 instances?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a generate block which runs at compile time (requires IEEE 1364-2001 or latter):

```
genvar i;
generate
for(i=0;i<16;i=i+1) begin : genblk
    BUF my_buf( .I(data[i]), .T(dir), .O(output[i]), .IO(to_phys_pin[i]) );
end
endgenerate
```

Another option is to create an array of instances (IEEE 1364-1995 or latter):

```
BUF my_buf[15:0]( .I(data[15:0]), .T({16{dir}}), .O(output[15:0]), .IO(to_phys_pin[15:0]) );
```

One difference from the two styles is the the hierarchical path name. http://www.edaplayground.com/s/6/94

Answer (score 1):

You should use generate:

```
  genvar i;
  generate
    for (i=0; i <= 15; i=i+1) begin
      BUF BUF(data[i], dir, out[i],
        to_phys_pin[i]);
    end
  endgenerate
```

Complete code, test, and sim results on EDA Playground: http://www.edaplayground.com/s/4/93